# Google login, Staying logged in through a refresh in react app

Tags: reactjs, google-signin

I've implemented a google login in my react app.  Currently I'm using react-google-login. The current behavior.  There are parts of the site you can use without a login like home and contact page and others
that can not be accessed until you login. we'll call that restricted page.
so current behavior is
User goes to url/   sees welcome message and clicks on login.
User is routed to url/login   there is a google login button.  User clicks it and logs in

Now if the user refreshes the page the app of course reloads and user is not logged in.  once they
navigates to url/login. as soon as the google button is rendered it sees the user has logged in (I assume this is from a cookie).

The issue is that is the user logs in and navigates to  url/restricted.  If they hit refresh then page reloads and react router will take them to page. in the component I have a check that if the user is not logged they get redirected to url/login and they they are automatically logged because of the recent cookie.

I want to make it so that if the user is on url/restricted and hit refresh I can check for the cookie and logged them in and not force them to navigate away from the page.  I figure I should ditch the react package and just use the google API directly. But looking at the docs I cant see how I can do the check and keep them logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there doesn't seem to be any way to auto login, even though google clearly has some information done in a cookie.

The solution was to take the information send back from google and manually store them in a cookie, then in app constructor read back the cookie and proceed.  At some point later I get into the token and checking if the token has expired since the last run of the app.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the process bit more?

Comment: Facing same issue now, Can you explain what you finally did ?